# How facebook does real time notification and how i can implement that on my website?

Tags: php, angularjs, facebook, symfony, socket.io

I have gone through many third party plugins which are paid so i decided to make to my own real time notification and chat functionality. I have checked [pusher](https://pusher.com/) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/). Where as guys i am using Angularjs in frontend and PHP [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) at backend.

Thanks

Comment: flagged as off-topic

Answer (score 0):

I believe facebook use custom websocket. There is also Server-Side Events (https://hpbn.co/server-sent-events-sse/).

There are some nice features baked into HTML2 involving server push functionality too, so that could be worth a look, although I dont think its intended as a direct replacement for the above.

Comment: I want to use same exactly functionality like facebook does or i get overview how facebook use websockets or else...